# Обратная свзязь belongTo и вывод blade. Laravel Framework 5.7.28

Tags: laravel, eloquent, blade

Есть два шаблона в первом всё нормально отображаеться во второом выходит ошибка :

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

С чем это может быть связано ?

У первого контролер UserController.php

```
   public function index()
{
    return view('user_managment.user.index',[
        'users' => User::paginate(10)
    ]);
}
```

первый шаблон index.blade.php

```
{{$user->roles->name}}
```

второй контролер RoleController.php

```
public function create()
{
    return view('role_managment.role.create',[
        'role' => '',
        'users' => User::all()
    ]);
}
```

второй шаблон create.blade.php

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
        {{$user->name}} 
        {{$user->roles->name}}

        {{-- @isset($user->roles->name)
            пользователя уже имеет роль  
        @endisset --}}
    </label>
    <br>
@endforeach
```

Модель Role

```
 public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Specialty','role','id');
}
```

Модель User

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User','role','id');
}
```

Comment: каким образом у вас описаны отношения между User и Role?

Comment: Добавил в описание вопроса данные модели

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том что в одном случае используется не та модель, по адресу

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;
```

А отношения были сделаны по адресу

```
use App\User;
```